# How to change device class of a bluetooth headset?

Tags: bluetooth

I have a bluetooth headset which is detected as keyboard. How to change it's device class in Ubuntu?

Comment: Did you look for its oid (first three hex pairs of its mac addr) in the /usr/share/gnome-bluetooth/pin-code-database.xml ?  That's one location to change the type'"keyboard" to type=""headset" or "headphones".

Comment: Tried to add it to that file. But still got it as keyboard. I looks that type in this file is used only to match device with pin.

Comment: late to the party, but I'm having the same issue. Really wonder why it can't be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I experienced the same thing and I use a Kali Linux  what I did was I copied the files from a working bluetooth device

`sudo nano /var/lib/bluetooth/EB:D4:3D:F5:C3:32/1C:6B:37:D2:D3:4B/info`

## J-800L (Head set seen as Keyboard)

I changed the class and services

```
Name=J-800L
Class=0x302540 # is the class of a KeyBoard
Services=00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb;0000110b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb;0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb;0000110d-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb;0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb;0000111e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb;00001124-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb;00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb;

# Services of KeyBoard
```

Copy from

```
 sudo nano /var/lib/bluetooth/EB:D4:3D:F5:C3:32/1B:6E:22:C3:F3:8B/info
```

## Q5 (Working Headset)

```
Name=Q5
Class=0x240404 # is the class of an Headset
Services=0000110b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb;0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb;0000110d-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb;0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb;0000111e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb;

# Services of an Headset
```

You can just use what I have for Q5 if you don't have a working headset

Then run the :

```
sudo systemctl restart bluetooth
```

or

```
sudo systemctl start bluetooth.service
```

I  hope this was helpful